# Can Cloud Foundry user-defined env variables set from buildpack?

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry, buildpack

In Cloud Foundry, user-defined env variables can be set using "cf set-env" command.

Can the same be set from buildpack programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking about creating a custom buildpack, or using one of the available CF buildpacks?

A buildpack sets the command that is used to launch an application, so if you are creating your own buildpack or customizing an existing one you can set env vars as part of that startup command. For example a startup command could like like this:

`VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2 some-command`

Comment: Another option is to write a `.profile.d/` script from the build pack.  These are sourced by the platform prior to your application starting.  I believe a lot of the standard build pack's do this to setup environment variables and configurations.

Comment: As an FYI, you can't just call `cf set-env` from the build pack.  *Unless* you were to install `cf` from your build pack and some how pass through user credentials for `cf` to use.  The platform doesn't do anything to assist you in this endeavor though.  Fortunately, you probably don't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks Scott and Daniel.  I will give it a try.  And no, I was not planning to us cf set-env from buildpack.  I know I can do it via cli and application manifest.  I tried to used ENV[], but it does not work.  I was wondering if there is any API or library